# stageX shifts with change in target position?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, mouseevent

The following code snippet is an event handler processing a `MouseEvent.CLICK`:

```
trace("me stageX:"+evt.stageX+" stageY:"+evt.stageY);
var placeX:int = evt.stageX-EasingWithMouse.CELL_WIDTH/2;
var placeY:int = evt.stageY-EasingWithMouse.CELL_HEIGHT/2;
stage.addChild(this);
this.x = placeX;
this.y = placeY;
trace("me stageX:"+evt.stageX+" stageY:"+evt.stageY);
```

The issue I'm having is `stageY` and `stageX` properties of the `evt` change after the object triggering the event is moved (by changing the x and y).

For example the trace on line one is `stageX:130 stageY:150`. This is shifted 0 on the x and -30 on the y. The trace on the last line now reports `stageX:130 stageY:120`.

To compound matters the new evt.stageX and evt.stageY is propogated through the rest of the event chain.

Is this what I should expect?

I ask because the reference document says:

> [read-only] The horizontal coordinate at which the event occurred in global Stage coordinates.

But I am not modifying anything in the global scope.

Here is a quick and dirty full example as requested:

the Main.as file:

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite{
        private var container:Sprite = new red1();//red1 is a symbol
        private var target:Sprite = new testreg1();//testreg1 is a symbol

        public function Main(){
            stage.addChild(container);
            container.x = 100;
            container.y = 100;
            container.addChild(target);
        }
    }
}
```

the testreg1.as file

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class testreg1 extends MovieClip{
        public function testreg1(){
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,meClick);
        }

        public function meClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("target stageX:"+evt.stageX+" stageY:"+evt.stageY);
            var placeX:int = evt.stageX-50;
            var placeY:int = evt.stageY-50;
            stage.addChild(this);
            this.x = placeX;
            this.y = placeY;
            trace("target stageX:"+evt.stageX+" stageY:"+evt.stageY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this was related to the fact that you are placing something outside of stage. I tried to reproduce this issue with setting different align modes and scalemodes, that didn't work. This does not hapen. When I read the evtents stageX and stageY-variables they are always the same inside the same function. You have to post more code, is the code really from the same function?

Comment: isn't `stage.addChild(this)` redundant? if yes, then there's your problem, you are moving the target of your event, which will naturally move everything with it

Comment: the lazy solution to this would be to clone your evt, stop the propagation, and dispatch the freshly cloned MouseEvent

Comment: @MartonPallagi no it is not redundant. I am intentionally moving the object from its container and placing it directly to the stage.

I am not sure one should expect a property tied to an event should change mid course. Shouldn't an event capture a state at a particular point in time regardless of what happens to the target after? I am not sure, I can see both sides of the issue.

I solved the problem by capturing the `stage.mouseX` and `stage.mouseY`